# Bootable USB doesn't show as boot option

Tags: boot, uefi, live-usb, usb-installation, rufus

I'm using a Dell Inspiron 5590, it came with Windows, I want to install Ubuntu instead. I downloaded the 18.04.5 image file and made a bootable USB device with Rufus following the [ubuntu tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). **The problem is, when booting, the USB device doesn't show in the Boot Options.**

What I've tried:

- Tested in USB ports 3.0 and 2.0
- Tested flash drive in another notebook (It works)
- Tested with and without Secure Boot.
- Tried two "builds" of the bootable USB: *Partition scheme: MBR + Target system: BIOS or UEFI* **AND** with *Partition scheme: GPT + Target system: UEFI (non CSM)*.

Also:

- I'm not looking to dual boot this, just linux is fine.
- USB Boot Support is enabled
- I didn't tried with Legacy Boot, because the BIOS says that this mode is not supported in the platform.
- Contacted Dell before purchase to be sure the hardware was compatible with Linux. (Also contacted the Dell support for help, useless in this case)
- BIOS is up to date.

What else can I try in order to have my bootable USB to be recognized by the Boot Manager?

Comment: Did you add the usb as a boot option in the bios?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Not sure how to do that. There is a field for enabling USB Boot Support, that is enabled.

Comment: I'll point out that folks have had issues with Rufus lately. You might want to give it another go with Balena Etcher.

Comment: @KGIII Ok, so I downloaded Balena Etcher, made a new bootable USB (balena doesnt seem to support custom configs.) but no luck. **still doesnt show up in boot manager.**

Comment: Do you have an option to push a button to select the boot device? It's often F12 to select a boot device. It varies by OEM and even by model, but it's frequently F12 or seldom F2.

Comment: Yes, it's F12, but the USB doesn't show up there. Just "Windows Boot Manager" and "UEFI Hard Drive".

Comment: This may give some inspiration: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if anyone is facing similar issues, I solved mine by replacing the USB flash drive.

It was a Sony 16gb, it works fine both within the OS and as a bootable device in other notebook, but for some reasons in this notebook it didn't. Replaced with a SanDisk 16gb and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Some BIOSes have difficulty with USB sticks over 4 GB. If the USB stick that you have tried previously is larger than that size, try one that is less than 4GB.

Comment: Ubuntu tutorial says to use one of 4GB or more https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#2-requirements . Also, not sure if they still make <4gb usb drives.